# Suitable value for EPS (machine epsilon?)

Tags: python, numpy, signals, fft

I am analyzing some time series acceleration data that I'd like to extract velocity and displacement from. It's apparent after much research that the best way to do this is in the frequency domain.

My language of choice is python and I came across [an excellent answer by @FuzzyDuck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28112601/4653485).

However the code sample uses an unreferenced variable `EPS`, which after some reading appears to be machine epsilon? What I don't understand is what it is exactly? What I read suggests that machine epsilon seems to be a constant value, obtainable via `numpy.finfo` or a number of other methods, but if this were the case why not just declare that value (`2.22044604925e-16`) rather than go through a function call? It seems to me there must be more to it...

I'd be grateful if someone could tell me if indeed `EPS` is machine epsilon, and if so should it be derived somehow or would `2.22044604925e-16` be suitable to use.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I think the `EPS` is only there to prevent a divide by zero, so it just needs to be a suitably small value.

Comment: @Jérôme, thanks for the edit, verbosity is one reason I'll never make my living writing code!

Comment: @Paul R , I appreciate the response, thanks. Using a small number (0.001) does appear to give an expected response, although I was puzzlied why not just use that instead of a variable name that suggested something more complex.

Comment: Well this is pretty much the context where you expect to use epsilon, i.e. the smallest representable non-zero value for a given data type. In this instance though the actual value is probably not crucial - it just needs to be much smaller than the other values in the expression.

Comment: @Paul R. Thank you! That helped me understand what epsilon actually is, and locate [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185953/machine-precision-and-max-and-min-value-of-a-double-precision-type) which further explains its use.